# Problem installing psi4 environment in jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, installation, jupyter-notebook, environment

I recently tryed to install psi4 into  a new jupyter environment on.

It worked for ten minuts at first and afterwards told me that py3.6 where missing gen.py files.

After some un-/reinstalling the environment it just stoped working all together.

Atm i'm using a bash script to install the environment.
if  i'm inside the activated environment after the psi4 installation and open python i'm able to import psi4.
However after deactivating the environment and starting a jupyter-notebook i'm unable to import psi4.

content of the bash file i curently use:

```
conda create --yes -n p4env python=3.6
conda activate p4env (p4env)
which python3.6 
conda install --yes python=3.6 psi4 psi4-rt -c psi4 
python3.6 "import psi4 
print(psi4.__version__)
" 
conda install --yes python=3.6 matplotlib 
conda install --yes python=3.6 ipykernel 
python3.6 -m ipykernel install --user --name p4env 
jupyter kernelspec list 
conda deactivate
conda env list
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the server already had preinstalled conda packages and i hadn't got sudo priveleges to the server, psi4  isn't persistently stored.

To work arround that you have to make a folder in your jupyter directory the folder of the package. 
I paste what worked for me below.

`conda_dir=$HOME/conda-psi4
    mkdir $conda_dir
    conda create --yes python=3.6 -p $conda_dir
    . /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
    conda activate $conda_dir
    conda install --yes python=3.6 psi4 psi4-rt -c psi4 -p $conda_dir
    conda install --yes p ython=3.6 matplotlib -p $conda_dir
    conda install --yes python=3.6 ipykernel -p $conda_dir
    python3.6 -m ipykernel install --user --name p4env
    jupyter kernelspec list
    conda deactivate
    conda env list`